# Is there a way to auto refresh Weibo access_token

Tags: weibo, sinaweibo

I'm working with the Weibo API, and access_tokens expire after seven days. They claim that there is a way that there should be a way to auto-refresh the token, but I can't find any documentation on it... has anyone dealt with this? (We aren't using the Weibo SDK, so we do not have a refresh_token)